# How can I get the response from an Ajax request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I tried this code :

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

function activecomm(comm_id,a_link_id)
{
    var postComm = "id="+encodeURIComponent(comm_id);
    var url = 'comments_mgr_proccesser.php'; 
    xmlHttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleInfo(a_link_id);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", postComm.length);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    xmlHttp.send(postComm);
}

function handleInfo(a_link_id)
{
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 1)
    {
        document.getElementById("commactiveresult").innerHTML = 'loading ..';
    }
    else if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
    {
        var response = xmlHttp.responseText;
        document.getElementById("commactiveresult").innerHTML = response;
    }
}
```

When `readyState == 1` the contents of the `commactiveresult` element is updated, but when `readyState == 4` nothing is shown in the same element.

Does anyone know what the problem is please?

Comment: in 'comments_mgr_proccesser.php' is :
**<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    include_once "../inc/DBconnection.php";
    $post_id = $_POST['id'];
    $active_comm = mysql_query("UPDATE `comments` SET `c_active`=1 WHERE
    `c_id`=$post_id") or die ("خطأ في الاستعلام التفعيل");
    if(isset($active_comm)){
        echo "تم التفعيل";
    }else{
        echo "خطأ في التفعيل";
    }

mysql_close($link);
?>**

Comment: That should be edited into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the `handleInfo` function instead of assigning a ready state handler. Try

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function (){
    handleInfo(a_link_id);
};
```